# How can I enter values to varchar(max) columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL-Server 2008 and concatenating string literals to more than 8000 characters by obvious modification of the following script, I always get the result 8000. Is there a way to tag string literals as varchar(max)?

DECLARE @t TABLE (test varchar(max));

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ( '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
+ '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
+ '... and 200 times the previous line'
);

select datalength(test) from @t

Comment: I don't understand your question. Data in a varchar column is essentially a string literal. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to fill a varchar(max) column via as T-SQL script.

Comment: @bernd_k I think RC answered your question as you stated it.  Your question is "How can I enter values to varchar(max) columns" not "How can I display more than 8k in SSMS when a column is varchar(max) and contains more than 8k?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted the question, I was convinced that there are some limitations for the length or maximal line width of a single string literal to be used in INSERT and UPDATE statement.

This assumption is wrong.

I was led to this impression by the fact the SSMS limits output width for a single column in text mode to 8192 characters and output of PRINT statements to 8000 characters.

Fact is, as far as I know you need only enclose the string with apostrophes and double all embedded apostrophes. I found no restrictions concerning width or total length of a string.

For the opposite task, to convert such strings back from database back to script the best tool I found is [ssms toolspack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) which works for SQL-Server 2005+.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code on SQL Server 2008

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [first] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [third] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
declare @maxVarchar varchar(max)
set @maxVarchar = (REPLICATE('x', 7199))
set @maxVarchar = @maxVarchar+(REPLICATE('x', 7199))

select LEN(@maxVarchar)

insert table_1( third)
values (@maxVarchar)
select LEN(third), SUBSTRING (REVERSE(third),1,1) from table_1
```

The value you are inserting in your example is being stored temporally as a varchar(8000) because.  To make the insert one will need to use a variable which is varchar(max) and append to it to overcome the internal 8000 limit.

Comment: Yes concatenation seems to require, that one of its components is already a varchar(max).

Comment: One partly elegant solution seems to be: Declare @vm varchar(max) = ''; INSERT INTO @t VALUES ( @vm + 'anything')

Comment: Oops I seem to have a problem. @ RC_Cleland I accepted your answer, because it inspired me to improve my T-SQL scripts generating SQL-Insert scripts. The main limitation SQL-Server is that PRINT only outputs 8000 chars.

Comment: Oops I'm very glad that I posed the question in a way, that I haven't to admit that I accepted the wrong answer. I did some investigation and found no limits concerning a limit in string length for INSERT or UPDATE statements. Main cause of the problem is, that the PRINT statement limits its output to 8000 characters and I can't use T-SQL to generate the statements using a longer string. But using external editors and executing the scripts in SSMS works fine.

Comment: Sorry This is not the best answer

Comment: @bernd_k I think RC answered your question as you stated it.  Your question is "How can I enter values to varchar(max) columns" not "How can I display more than 8k in SSMS when a column is varchar(max) and contains more than 8k?"

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your value being inserted as a varchar(max):

```
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (CAST('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
+ '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
+ '... and 200 times the previous line' AS varchar(max)
);
```

Also, you may have to concatenate several <8000 length strings (each casted as varchar(max)).

See this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/6cdd2549-4989-4b4a-9269-13961904cbdb).

Comment: I wonder, how could a cast add data, that isn't present in the result of the concatination?